# Can I choose which frames to render in an animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes

I want to analyse an existing movie clip for edit points. At each edit point along the length of this clip I would like to render the frame found there. I would like to discard the rest of the frames... or simply not save them at all. I know that I can stipulate a render range from command line when running Blender headless, but I need it to be a dynamic variable, as I don't know when each frame will be chosen to save.

Here is the edit point discovery nodes. I subtract the movie from itself by a difference of one frame then use the Levels node to pass an average value to the math node to act as a boolean. Currently this lets me write a black frame (Discard Frame) or the edit point frame (Keep Frame).

If I cannot simply restrict the frames written then I would like to send the Keep Frames to a different folder than the Discard Frames (I can delete them later). Or I could remove the unique frame sequence number code from Discard Frames so they overwrite themselves. Maybe the File Node could do this?

[image: Edit point detector]

Comment: You know how to render headless via command line. Why not writing a shell script with a variable which drives the rendering of the one exact frame you’d like to have rendered?

Comment: There's no way to know which frame I want until the compositor checks the source